# ansible : running include_tasks in parallel for all the hosts

Tags: ansible

have the following yaml file, abc.yml

```
    - name: Create DBsystem(s)
      include_tasks:
        file: createDbsystemSub.yaml
        apply:
          tags:
            - createDbsystem
      vars:
        nodename: "{{inventory_hostname.split('.')[0]}}"
        machinesvar: "{{machines[nodename]}}"
      loop: "{{createDbsystem}}"
      tags: [createDbsystem,never]
      ignore_errors: yes
```

Content of file, createDbsystemSub.yaml is as below.

```
    - name : Print the item
      debug:
        msg: "{{item.name}}"

    - name: Execute Dbsystem Creation
      include_tasks:
        file: createDbsystems.yaml
      vars:
        targetserver_var: "{{targetserver_dbsystems}}"
        dbsystem_item: "{{item}}"
      loop: "{{machinesvar.dbsystems}}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: targetserver_dbsystems
        label: "{{ targetserver_dbsystems }}"
      when: item.name == targetserver_dbsystems["dbsystem"]
```

I want to run the tasks in createDbsystems.yaml parallely on all the hosts but this just runs on the first host and then moves on to the second host. Is there a way I can run these parallely on all the hosts ?

I read this link from SO but couldn't understand the logic behind this.
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/36978

Answer (score 0):

No, include has to work serially, it is a significant part of the include_tasks / import_tasks tradeoff.

The main reason is that the file that is included can be dynamic.  You can run include_tasks: "{{ ansible_hostname }}.yml". In this instance the tasks which are executed are completely different from host to host, so they can't be run and reported in parallel.

In your actual example the loop means that the number of iterations is dynamic, so for each spin of the loop there would be different hosts involved and it would all become very complex.

Another way of achieving parallel execution is to set the playbook strategy: free. This runs all tasks on all hosts in parallel and doesn't bother trying to align the reporting.